# Calculate timeleft

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm making an application that has a function that calculate time, if it's already past the expired time it should pop up a message saying "session has expired" something like that.

Here's I calculate time:

```
  CurrentTime := StrToDateTime('10/10/15 10:02');
  TimeExpired := StrToDateTime('10/10/15 10:00');

  iHours := HoursBetween(CurrentTime, TimeExpired );
  iMinutes := MinutesBetween(CurrentTime, TimeExpired )- (iHours * 60 );
```

Problem there is it doesn't give a negative value (-2).

I normally just calculate the hours and minutes left, but if my application crashes or accidentally closed, and the user reopened it again and it already past the expiration time, the minutes left increases instead of decreasing.

How do I know if the time already expired ?

Comment: Why did you not read the documentation? The documentation makes a very clear statement that will answer your question. Do you know how to find documentation? Perhaps that's the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply check which time is greater. If `CurrentTime > TimeExpired`, then the expiration time is in the past, and the session has obviously expired.

Comment: yeah thats what Im looking for, is just my English is not good, i dont know what words to use it on google, now that you mention which time is  greater :D I'm using now CompareDateTime